# Creating a static library (.a) in C++ (Not for iOS)

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, static-libraries

I'm trying to make a C++ wrapper for Unity3D in C# based in OpenCV but first of all I'm trying to make a `.a` static library in C++ in order to make the wrapper.
(I don't know if I'm doing right this).

But my problem is on building a new static library with Xcode.

(PD: I'm asking this question because Google is full of "how to make a static library for iOS and that's not what I'm looking for).

I make: New -> Project -> Mac OSx Frameworks and Libraries -> Library (Static, STL framework).

Then I have my two files: `.h` and `.cp`

**file1.cp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "/Users/rafaelruizmunoz/Documents/OpenCV_projects/OpenCVDebug/OpenCVDebug/mylib.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

float* prueba_funcion(unsigned char* a, int cols, int rows) {
    Mat mat = Mat(rows, cols, CV_8U, a);
    float* o = giveMeMiddlePoints(mat); // this function gets called from the include
    return o;

}
```

**file1.h**

```
#ifndef file1_
#define file1_

/* The classes below are exported */
#pragma GCC visibility push(default)

class file1
{
    public:
        float* prueba_funcion(unsigned char *, int, int);
};

#pragma GCC visibility pop
#endif
```

I press Cmd + B to build the library and I try to make a new Command Line project (for testing), importing my **libfile1.a** and my header **file1.h** in the Command Line project:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "/Users/rafaelruizmunoz/Desktop/file1.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";

    unsigned char data[9] = {3,3,3,1,9,1,2,2,2};

    file1 f;
    float* q = f.prueba_funcion(data, 3, 3);
    cout << endl << q;

    return 0;
}
```

but I get linker errors (it's like if my static library was compiled in a wrong way):

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "file1::prueba_funcion(unsigned char*, int, int)", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Do you know what I'm really doing bad?

Thank you in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `file1.cpp`, instead of

```
float* prueba_funcion(unsigned char* a, int cols, int rows)
```

write

```
float* file1::prueba_funcion(unsigned char* a, int cols, int rows)
```

Otherwise you're not defining a member function of `file1` but a free function that just happens to have the same name.

Oh, and you'll have to `#include "file1.h"` in `file1.cpp` to make the class definition known there.

Comment: Thank you very much... I'm really newbie at some points in C++ (I just make Command Tool :D )